# Converted string not in correct format

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

First of all, I am aware that there's numerous questions like mine, but after analyzing them, I get an idea of what to do, but ultimately keep getting errors.
I'm using visual studio 2012 and c++ language to create a time card windows form as shown below.
http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b618/uRsh3RRaYm0nD/checkin_zpsa4ccebda.jpg

As you can see, I was able to convert and calculate the datetimepicker range values to string in order to show those values underneath the Hours text box.
Where I'm having trouble is coding the Total Hours Get button that will subtract both Hour's text boxes, in order to display them in the Total Hours text box.
I've tried converting those string values back to DateTime, performing the calculation, and then converting the result to string to display it.

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         if( this->dtpMondayIn->Value > this->dtpMondayOut->Value )
     this->dtpMondayIn->Value = this->dtpMondayOut->Value;
         System::TimeSpan diff = this->dtpMondayOut->Value.Subtract(this->dtpMondayIn->Value);
         txtMonday->Text = Convert::ToString(diff);
     }
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         if(this->dtpLunchIn->Value > this->dtpLunchOut->Value)
             this->dtpLunchIn->Value = this->dtpLunchOut->Value;
         System::TimeSpan diff2 = this->dtpLunchOut->Value.Subtract(this->dtpLunchIn->Value);
         txtLunch->Text = Convert::ToString(diff2);
     }
private: System::Void get1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            DateTime lunch, work, total;
            lunch = Convert::ToDateTime(txtLunch->Text);
            work = Convert::ToDateTime(txtLunch->Text);
            total = lunch - work;
            txtTotalHours->Text = Convert::ToString(total);
//This is where I get the error  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::TimeSpan' to 'System::DateTime
```

Comment: I don't see any C# here; and that code is *impossible* to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TimeSpan` to calculate durations. DateTime does what it says on the tin, it represents a moment in time.

```cpp
private: System::Void get1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    TimeSpan work, lunch, total;

    work = this->dtpMondayOut->Value.Subtract(this->dtpMondayIn->Value);
    lunch = this->dtpLunchOut->Value.Subtract(this->dtpLunchIn->Value);
    total = lunch - work;

    txtTotalHours->Text = Convert.ToDecimal(total->TotalHours).ToString("#.00");
}
```

**Edit**: Changed txtTotalHours output to match decimal output of provided image.